# Why does kafka wants data to be binary (array of bytess) in topics?

Tags: serialization, apache-kafka

I wanted to know the advantages that come to kafka from converting data to be binary (array of bytess) in topics?(serialization)

thanks.

Comment: occupies less storage, faster I/O, less data through the wire, faster to read (just a size, no newlines or anything like that), and binary lets you pass text, images, mp3, gzip, etc, etc. The question should be, why shouldn't kafka want data to be binary? : )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An Extract from Kafka: Definitive Guide

> A message is simply an array of bytes as far as Kafka is concerned, so
>   the data contained within it does not have a specific format or
>   meaning to Kafka. A message can have an optional bit of metadata,
>   which is referred to as a key. The key is also a byte array and, as
>   with the message, has no specific meaning to Kafka.

So the real question here is: **What are the benefits of storing data in byte array?**

Byte array is a generic data format and virtually any data type that we know of (or custom ones created by developers) can be Serialized/deserialized to/from a byte array.

**@aran** gave great examples in the comment.  Just to add another reason, we don't need to care about the schemas and validation of messages in Kafka. It's just a store... Imagine 500 applications running and producing/consuming to/from kafka. There can be 500 different schemas and data types (String, Int, Json, XML etc.) and more than 500 validation criterion for the messages. But, these are application end operations. So, a messaging platform like Kafka should not care about these formats and should provide a generic way to store all types of data which it clearly does. :)

Hope that helps! :)

Comment: great explanation  : )